# I suspect a program may be sending data to servers secretly. How can I check?

Tags: monitoring

What is the easiest way to monitor whether a program (which shouldn't be using the network at all) is sending data to outside servers without my knowledge? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use netstat to see all of the programs that are listening on or using the network.

`netstat -plntu` will show you all programs that are currently listening on some interface and port.

`netstat -an` will show you which programs and processes are currently using the network.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Time to go through hundreds of entries...

Comment: @user1389840 You can also use grep to find a specific program easier. :) For example if I was looking for firefox I could say `netstat -an | grep firefox`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo lsof -cprogram_name` to list all the open files and sockets of the named program. `man lsof` is good, too.